# the mouseover function in my website is causing the image to flick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a blank map in my website that has four coloured squares that when i pass the mouse over one of them the png of the map changes showing the route of the colour, but when I do that the image changes its position and bugs the "hitbox" of the other squares, making it very hard to get what you want.
This is the link to the page:[link](https://www.arcanjohotel.com/localizacao/)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="gdlr-content">

        <!-- Above Sidebar Section-->
        <?php global $gdlr_post_option, $above_sidebar_content, $with_sidebar_content, $below_sidebar_content; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($above_sidebar_content)){ ?>
            <div class="above-sidebar-wrapper"><?php gdlr_print_page_builder($above_sidebar_content); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        
        <!-- Sidebar With Content Section-->
        <?php 
            if( !empty($gdlr_post_option['sidebar']) && ($gdlr_post_option['sidebar'] != 'no-sidebar' )){
                global $gdlr_sidebar;
                
                $gdlr_sidebar = array(
                    'type'=>$gdlr_post_option['sidebar'],
                    'left-sidebar'=>$gdlr_post_option['left-sidebar'], 
                    'right-sidebar'=>$gdlr_post_option['right-sidebar']
                ); 
                $gdlr_sidebar = gdlr_get_sidebar_class($gdlr_sidebar);
        ?>
            <div class="with-sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="with-sidebar-container container">
                    <div class="with-sidebar-left <?php echo esc_attr($gdlr_sidebar['outer']); ?> columns">
                        <div class="with-sidebar-content <?php echo esc_attr($gdlr_sidebar['center']); ?> columns">
                            <?php 
                                if( !empty($with_sidebar_content) ){
                                    gdlr_print_page_builder($with_sidebar_content, false);
                                }
                                if( !empty($gdlr_post_option['show-content']) && $gdlr_post_option['show-content'] != 'disable' ){
                                    get_template_part('single/content', 'page');
                                }
                            ?>                          
                        </div>
                        <?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>              
            </div>              
        <?php 
            }else{ 
                if( !empty($with_sidebar_content) ){ 
                    echo '<div class="with-sidebar-wrapper">';
                    gdlr_print_page_builder($with_sidebar_content);
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                if( empty($gdlr_post_option['show-content']) || $gdlr_post_option['show-content'] != 'disable' ){
                    get_template_part('single/content', 'page');
                }
            } 
        ?>
        
        <!-- Below Sidebar Section-->
        <?php if(!empty($below_sidebar_content)){ ?>
            <div class="below-sidebar-wrapper"><?php gdlr_print_page_builder($below_sidebar_content); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
                    
    </div><!-- gdlr-content -->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Início do código para o hover no mapa - colocar no final do arquivo html -->


<map name="legenda" id="legenda">
    <area alt="bh" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="744,728,977,748" />
    <area alt="mariana" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,767,922,785" />
    <area alt="ob" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,803,959,820" />
    <area alt="transfer" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,839,1087,860" />
</map>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      imageMapResize();
    $('#legenda area').each(function () {
    // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
      var id = "#" + $(this).attr('alt');
      $(id).show();
      $("#base").hide();
    });

    // Assigning an action to the mouseout event
    $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
      var id = "#" + $(this).attr('alt');
      $(id).hide();
      $("#base").show();
    });

  });
</script>

    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

it was supposed to work fine :(

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<br>`s from in between the images, then it becomes much closer to the desired result. To fix that remaining space, I placed all images into the exact same `<div>`, and then it works perfectly.

Personally, I would place the 4 colored squares outside the map, as it isn't entirely clear that hovering over the squares would change the map.

Comment: It didn't worked ;-;

Comment: It worked when I tried it, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: it is still flicking, do you still have the code that worked? maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Well I didn't save the code, all I did was edit the webpage in my browser until it worked. If you inspect element on your website and jump to the img with the id "bh", you will see the <br> elements that are added in between each images, and that is messing with the spacing of the elements.

Comment: thank you so much! when I was editing the page in text editor the <br> wasn't appearing, but when i inspected it I saw it, now I can make it work, thanks